# How to save the user's id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a simple blogsite where people can signin by using Facebook Connect and JS SDK.

If I get the user's id via javascript then how can I securely save it in my mysql database ? I have to use ajax ?
Thanks

Comment: You write it to your database... Any way you want... Might be AKAX but it could be using any method. What do you mean secure?

Comment: someone can edit javascript on the page and insert anything in my database.

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with Facebook.  What you want to look into is SQL vulnerabilities... and specifically  **preventing them**...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a component package that can manage that for you. There is an example for you:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Helper-Component-Community/222933037808340?sk=app_412923142052609

With this package you are able to let users login and save their access_token + user_ids to access their data or to post to their profiles. This package easily wraps the functionality of the JS SDK into a nice workflow which is easy to understand and easy to extend.